# Retrieve xml serialize output string to replace single quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml-serialization

This is how im serializing an object. How to I retrieve the xml string to replace the single quotes?

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {OmitXmlDeclaration = true};

            settings.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

            var writer = XmlWriter.Create(writeStream, settings);

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());

            var nameSpaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

            nameSpaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

            serializer.Serialize(writer, value, nameSpaces);
```

Comment: You don't have to: that is the job of the serializer.  have you actually tried this and you are getting unescaped single quotes in your xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize to a text writer and do required string manipulations such as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var value = new Class1() { SomeProperty = "content' asdasd' asdasd" };
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        Encoding = Encoding.ASCII
    };
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1));
    string output = string.Empty;

    var nameSpaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    nameSpaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value, nameSpaces);
        }
        output = textWriter.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    string newOutput = output.Replace('\'', 'x');
    Console.WriteLine(newOutput);
}
```

In this example the output would be

```
<Class1><SomeProperty>content' asdasd' asdasd</SomeProperty></Class1>
<Class1><SomeProperty>contentx asdasdx asdasd</SomeProperty></Class1>
```